# Loud popping from back seat doors alternating left to right in 2001 Mercedes ml320

Tags: noise, troubleshooting, mercedes-benz, door

While driving heard what sounded like something maybe in back seat hitting passenger door. It then made a pretty loud pop or bang. Then noise moved to drivers side. Then back to passenger. Stopped for a while. Then started again. Didn’t matter if car was moving or stopped. Always alternates sides. Kind of spooky. Like there’s a little gremlin running around trying to get in. Or out
2001 Mercedes ml320

Comment: Not on a Merc, but I once had a heat shield on the exhaust come loose. It was "trapped" between the floor pan and the exhaust so it couldn't completely fall off, but strong winds, or close-passing vehicles, rocked the car enough to make it bang against the exhaust and/or the car body. Maybe you have something similar going on!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Coming from the rear loudspeakers, possibly?